# Convert specific RGB (GeoTIFF) color to transparent

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity, rgb

I have an RGB GeoTIFF file and I want to convert a specific RGB colour to transparent. I would like to use GDAL for doing this, but external Python scripts are also an option (though I haven't learned the art of Python scripting yet).

My thoughts are:

1. Add a 4th band to my GeoTIFF file and fill with 255.
2. Insert 0 into the 4th band where RGB colour == *target colour*

The first part I think I can solve using

```
gdalwarp -dstalpha source.tif target.tif
```

The second though I don't know how to solve. **[matt wilkie](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/108/matt-wilkie)** [suggest](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/2929/205) using a Python script he wrote, but I think that is done separately for *each band* and not for a *specific colour*.

**How can I assign a value to the 4th band of my TIFF when the RGB colour is equal to a specific RGB colour?**

Comment: Which colour are you wanting to make transparent? Also, colour  can be pretty arbitary because it is based on a set of numbers between 0 - 255 on 3 scales. You'd have to specify the exact range of colour you wanted to make transparent.

Comment: I want to make a *specific colour* - not a range of colours - transparent. A range would also be nice to have, but at the moment a specific colour will do. I specified that I am working with an RGB image, and it might be me simplifying stuff, but I assume that *a colour* is an RGB colour, thus a combination of values in all 3 bands. I apologise for any unclear asumptions :)

Answer (score 11):

here's a better answer, use [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html) with either srcnodata or vrtnodata flag:

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "123 231 67" outfile.vrt input.tif
```

If the next application in line doesn't understand .vrt, translate to a new tif:

```
gdal_translate outfile.vrt final.tif
```

Comment: cool! Although NODATA integrity is lost when passing to GTiff: in this case `gdalinfo` would report `123` as NODATA value for each band (GDAL 2.1.1 here)

Answer (score 4):

Herein lies a misunderstanding: *"...that is done separately for each band and not for a specific colour."*

"Each band" and "specific colour" are in fact the same thing. That is, it is the values in each band that, when combined together, make a specific colour. For example the RGB triplet `255,0,0` is the specific colour of pure red, comprised of band-red at the top of the range, 255, and band-green at the bottom, 0, ditto for band-blue.

Here's a simple gdal python script to change the nodata values for a specific image with 3 channels, a.k.a RGB:

```
from osgeo import gdal

input = 'd:/gisdata/test.tif'
dataset = gdal.Open(input, gdal.GA_Update)  # open the raster for writing

# 1 corresponds to Red channel, 2 for Green, 3 for Blue
R = dataset.GetRasterBand(1)
G = dataset.GetRasterBand(2)
B = dataset.GetRasterBand(3)

print 'Initial nodata values (RGB):\t', R.GetNoDataValue(), G.GetNoDataValue(), B.GetNoDataValue()

# set null value to the background page colour used on GIS.se, change as desired
R.SetNoDataValue(251)
G.SetNoDataValue(250)
B.SetNoDataValue(247)

print 'New nodata values (RGB):\t', R.GetNoDataValue(), G.GetNoDataValue(), B.GetNoDataValue()
```

Output:

```
D:\>python setnull.py
Initial nodata values (RGB):  None None None
New nodata values (RGB):      251.0 250.0 247.0
```

A more generalized script that can handle arbitrary numbers of bands and used as a commandline utility can be found my [code swamp](http://code.google.com/p/maphew/source/browse/gis/), as [gdalsetnull.py](http://code.google.com/p/maphew/source/browse/gis/o4w_extras/bin/gdalsetnull.py)

Comment: This won't work for GeoTiffs, at least persistently.  GeoTiffs can't have different Nodata values for different bands.  If you close the dataset and re-open it, all the no data values will be 247.  You may need to wrap it with a vrt to get it to work.

Comment: That's interesting @kyle. What program are you closing and re-opening with where persistence doesn't work?

Comment: It's a shortcoming (or not) of the geotiff format/driver, it looks like you submitted the ticket:
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2083

Comment: @kyle hah! that's funny, and embarrassing. I guess that means I'm earning my grey hairs, don't remember some of my own work. :)