# Create Alpha band in GeoTIFF to make a specific color transparent using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, raster-calculator, transparency-opacity

I have a simple RGB GeoTIFF with a white background and want to add a 4th band, the alpha, so that if R+G+B=255*3, then ALPHA=0 ; i.e. if all three bands have a value of 255, then make the fourth zero (or some other number).

This question has been asked before [on stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25064/gdal-convert-specific-rgb-geotiff-color-to-transparent) but all the answers provided are not working for me.

So far I have tried:

```
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata "255 255 255" -addalpha outfile.vrt infile.tif
gdal_translate outfile.vrt outfile-alpha.tif
```

but this seems to be an OR statement, where if one band is 255, then it is nodata for the whole pixel so a lot of other colors are wiped out as well.

I tried:

```
gdal_calc.py -A in.tif --A_band=1 -B in.tif --B_band=2 -C in.tif --C_band=3 ^
 --outfile=alpha.tif --calc="255*((A+B+C)<(765))" --overwrite
```

And this resulted in a single-band raster with 255 in every cell.

I tried the same with `--calc="A+B+C"` just to see and the all the white cells added up to 253, rather than 765. Is it some kind of modulus thing? No idea...

I have managed to add alpha bands to a white background using QGIS' Raster Calculator using ORs: `((Band@1 <255) OR (Band@2 <255) OR (Band@3 <255))*255` , but I want to be able to do it through GDAL, so that I can do batch processing.

Comment: When you sum the rasters via gdal_calc.py, the reason you get 253 may be due to the datatype. If your geotiff is stored as a uint8, for example, the maximum value a cell can have is 256. You could try saving the raster as uint16 then performing the calculation.

Comment: Yes, that actually worked! I had to explode the original RGB tiff into three separate tiffs - one for each band with the UInt16 type and then plug those three into gdal_calc.py to get a result. I had thought of this before, but had modified only the output file - I didn't realize the input files also have to be in the right type. Feel free to write up your comment in a short answer, so I can accept it!

Comment: I'll let you write the answer so you can provide some code that you used to solve the problem :) I'm too lazy to look up the commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some help from [Jon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/78446/jon), here is an answer:

```
set pathin=D:\procbox\In
set pathout=D:\procbox\Out


FOR %%N in (%pathin%\*.tif) DO (^
gdal_calc.py -A %%N --A_band=1  --outfile=A.tif --calc="A" --overwrite --type="UInt16" & ^
gdal_calc.py -A %%N --A_band=2  --outfile=B.tif --calc="A" --overwrite --type="UInt16" & ^
gdal_calc.py -A %%N --A_band=3  --outfile=C.tif --calc="A" --overwrite --type="UInt16" & ^
gdal_calc.py -A A.tif --A_band=1 -B B.tif --B_band=1 -C C.tif --C_band=1 ^
--outfile=%pathout%\%%~nN-cov.tif --calc="255*((A+B+C)==765)" --overwrite --type="UInt16")

FOR %%N in (%pathout%\*-cov.tif) DO gdal_polygonize.py %%N -f "ESRI Shapefile" -mask %%N %pathout%\%%~nN.shp
```

What this script does is it sequentially processes all .tif files in a directory, breaks them down into individual RGB bands (A,B,C .tif) and then calculates a new raster with 255 whenever all these three rasters add up to white (765). What was important was that I was working with a UInt8 tiff, and the input tiffs need to be at least UInt16 for the calculation not to loop over 255.

Then it creates a shapefile around all the white areas. I use this to check survey coverage. If you use the script, please note that in Windows BAT files you break rows with the `^` symbol, rather than with a backslash escape (`\`) like with shell scripting in Linux.